# CPU in android device

Tags: android, cpu-usage, android-logcat

I Download some jar library and added to my project and i notice in LOGCAT that there thousands of printing (i guess with Log.d). Can it effect cpu performances?

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on the cause of the thing which results in Logging like that.

It can effect the cpu performance since it's performing something in the background all the time and also there's probably some stuff going on background which leads to that logs so you better check your processes and see what's causing that also check your app's cpu and resource consumption via a system monitor or logcat.